# Does the saliva of a person just recovered from an infectious disease help to cure another persons having the same disease?

Tags: infection, immune-system, dosage, saliva, antibodies

I have always had this 'weird' thought (But could never quite test it...). Would the saliva contain antibodies, or other immuno-boosting substances that can help fight off the same pathogen in another person? If yes, is the concentration (dose) of them in saliva enough to have any considerable effect directly (without any further artificial concentration or extraction done)?

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting question, and I'm greatly looking forward to the answer

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist  Thanks but sadly no one gives a fxxk haha. Maybe somebody can help to migrate it to Bio SE?